# Spock test won't run with a new spring-boot project created by start.spring.io

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

Spock tests run fine in the IDE but will not execute in the maven build.

To recreate the issue

1. Go to https://start.spring.io/ and create a new Groovy / Maven project, keep all other defaults.
2. Add the spock dependency to the pom:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

3. Add a failing spock test named HelloSpec.groovy next to the existing test:

```java
import spock.lang.Specification

class HelloSpec extends Specification {
  def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"() {
    expect:
    name.size() == length

    where:
    name     | length
    "Spock"  | 5
    "Kirk"   | 4
    "Scotty" | 6
    "Dave"   | 911
  }
}
```

4. add the maven surefire plugin to the build so it knows to pick up the spock test. I understand this is supposed to be automatic for files ending in Spec but I haven't found that to be so. I also understand the file doesn't end in .java, that it is in fact a .groovy file, just go with it.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

5. Run mvn clean install from the command line. You will find you are on false greenbar and the spock test does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6. Remove the exclusion of the junit-vintage-engine that Spring added to your spring-boot-starter-tests dependency

```xml
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
```

7. Run mvn clean install from the command line. Spock tests are picked up and run and your build correctly fails with the failing test

Comment: Leonard: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"